# How does template argument deduction for f(T&()) happen?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, template-argument-deduction

I was reading the standard, and couldn't figure out how the following code compiles.

```
template <class T>
void f(T&()) {}

double d = 0;
double& g() { return d; }

int main() {
    f(g);
}
```

[[temp.deduct.type]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.deduct.type#8) provides a list of cases where the deduction occurs:

> A template type argument T, a template template argument TT or a template non-type argument i can be deduced if P and A have one of the following forms:
> T
> cv T
> T*
> T&
> T&&
> ...

For `P = T&()` in my case, it doesn't seems to match any of the forms in the list.

Did I miss any rules for template deduction, or is the list not comprehensive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in [temp.deduct.type#11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.deduct.type#11)

> These forms can be used in the same way as `T` is for further composition of types.

It might be clearer if you write your template with a different typename than `T`, e.g.

```
template <class U>
void f(U&()) {}
```

so now you can see that `U&()` is of the form `T()`, where `U&` is a variant of `T&`.

Comment: Oh, so is the `T&` in the list intended to be used **only** in a composition of types, for _If P is a reference type, the type referred to by P is used for type deduction_?

Comment: No, it can be used as a plain `T&` type as well, it doesn't only have to be used in a composition.